# Fluent NHibernate session not working in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have Fluent NHibernate set up in an ASP.NET web application. I have an http module that intercepts the requests and creates a new session for each one:

```
private static void BeginRequest( object sender, EventArgs e )
{

    ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();

    session.BeginTransaction();

    CurrentSessionContext.Bind( session );
}
```

It is configured like so:

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    return Fluently
        .Configure()
        .Database( MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
            .ConnectionString( c => c
                .FromConnectionStringWithKey( "RecruitmentApp" ) ) )
        .Mappings( 
            m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<RecruitmentAppLibrary.Applicant>()
        )
        .ExposeConfiguration( c => c.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass, "web"))
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

I do set the current session context class to "web", however the code can't get the session when _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession() is called. It says "No session bound to the current context". I've debugged it a bit and the session is being inserted into the Http context, but it can't pull it back out for some reason (even though it is still in the context when my Page_Load is called). Any ideas?

Comment: When are you unbinding the session context?  Put a breakpoint where you are doing that and make sure you are not unbinding it before you attempt to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ManagedWebSessionContext instead of CurrentSessionContext:

```
ManagedWebSessionContext.Bind(HttpContext.Current, session);
```